# Visual Studio alternative for Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, programming, monodevelop

I write programs in Windows casually (apps like notepad, web-browser etc.). But I don't see a good alternative available. I have used Mono but it is not one bit like Visual Studio. I am having a tough time to figure out stuff. The apps that I write look something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://google.com")
End Sub
```

and the have a blank forum and I add stuff like combo-box, buttons etc. Then I right-click those and write the code for it (see above bold). I found nothing like that in in Mono. Perhaps I am mistaken or confused.

Comment: are you looking for an IDE? If yes [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is available for linux.

Comment: No, I understand, he's looking for a GUI designer tool.

Comment: do u want a good editor ? if yes then `vi editor` is there in ubuntu as in any linux. You can search for vi tuorial in google and you will find good help. `vi editor` is a tough editor to learn but you can do things more easily once you learn. I am also learning it so ...

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for an IDE for a specific language? Or an "all-in-one" IDE? Check out [Anjuta](http://www.anjuta.org/) and [QT Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/). Also see [this list of alternatives to Visual Studio for Linux](http://alternativeto.net/software/visual-studio/?platform=linux)

EDIT: QT Creator has a good GUI designer called...take a guess...QT Designer. Is that what you're looking for?